# Slick how to sort by a option column got from left join

Tags: scala, slick

At first, get all the children comments in a subquery

```scala
    val getChildCommentStatQuery =
      Tbcomments
        .filter(row =>
          row.itargetid === commentTargetId && row.iparentid =!= 0 && row.istatus === statusNormal)
        .groupBy(_.iparentid)
        .map { case (parentId, group) =>
          // return parent commentId，the number of all the children，and the sum of like of all the children
          (parentId, group.size, group.map(_.ilikecount).sum)
        }
```

Secondly, use Table Tbcomments to left join with subquery table got in the first step.

```scala
    val query =
      Tbcomments
        .joinLeft(getChildCommentStatQuery)
        .on(_.iid == _._1)
        .filter { case (comments, _) =>
          // got the first level comment whose parentid equals to 0
          comments.itargetid === commentTargetId && comments.iparentid === 0 && comments.istatus === statusNormal
        }
        .map { case (comments, childComments) =>
          val replyCount = childComments.map(_._2)
          val likeCountSum = comments.ilikecount + childComments.map(_._3.getOrElse(0))
          val hot = replyCount + likeCountSum
          val support = comments.ilikecount - comments.inotlikecount
          (comments.iid, replyCount, likeCountSum, hot, support, comments.dtcreated)
        }
        .sortBy(row =>
          sortOrder match {
            case LATEST_COMMENT_ORDER   => row._6.desc
            case EARLIEST_COMMENT_ORDER => row._6.asc
            case SUPPORT_COMMENT_ORDER  => row._5.desc
//            case HEAT_COMMENT_ORDER     => row._4.get
          })
```

The problem is, the row._4 is a field aggregate based on right table, and in the left join case it's an option. It seems can't sortBy the option field directly.

Thanks!

Comment: You want it to sort on a column which may be empty. So the question becomes, what should happen in that case? Say you want it to be treated as `0`, then you could do something like `row._4.getOrElse(0).asc`

Comment: Thanks! In fact, i have tried row._4.getOrElse(0), but forgot to specifying "asc" or "desc"……@Raf

Comment: hey Bro, you should have answered under my question so that i can upvote you :)@Raf